# Moving Boolean Values to Another Function C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need to move the value isAMFut and isAM into the function computeDifference()

```
cout<<"Is it AM or PM?"<<endl;
cin>>amOrPMFut;
transform(amOrPMFut.begin(), amOrPMFut.end(), amOrPMFut.begin(), ::toupper);
//Checking if user enters am or pm
while ((amOrPMFut != "AM") && (amOrPMFut != "PM")){
    cout<<"Is it AM or PM?"<<endl;
    cin>>amOrPMFut;
    transform(amOrPMFut.begin(), amOrPMFut.end(), amOrPMFut.begin(), ::toupper);
}
if (amOrPMFut == "AM"){
    isAMFut = true;
}
else {
    isAMFut = false;
}
```

I would like to accomplish this by using pointers if that is possible. Otherwise I was thinking I could create the two booleans as global scope variables, but I don't feel like that is the most practical. Any insight would be much appreciated, please let me know if I can clear anything up.

Thanks!

```
int computeDifference(int& hours, int& minutes, int& hourFut, int& minFut){
    //Calculations
    //NEED TO TRANSFER VALUES OF BOOLEANS FROM MAIN FUNCTION INTO THIS FUNCTION
    if ((isAM == true) && (isAMFut == true) {
        if (hours > hourFut) {
            diffHr = abs((hours - hourFut - 24));
            diffMin = abs((minutes - minFut));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not take them in as `const bool&` parameters in the function?

Comment: A consistent and readable indentation of code will make your question easier to read.

Comment: Or just `bool`. It doesn't make much sense to have constant references on primitive types.

Comment: if I use the const tag will the value change as I run it through the program or would it just stay at its default value?

Comment: You will not be able to change it in `computeDifference`.  If you need to change it then just pass it as a reference like all of your other parameters.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not trying to change it in computeDifference, I want the values to be read in from my main function, the booleans acquire the values in the main and I want those values to be used in this function.

Comment: @StenSoft True.  I am just so used to doing that and I don't think it matters.  Since a reference is not required to have any storage it may actually be more performant.

Comment: Maybe what you have shown is incomplete, but you're only doing something if both `isAM` and `isAMFut` are true, so why not check them before calling `computeDifference`? Then `computeDifference` doesn't even need them.

Comment: @DigitalNinja for this particular case yes, both are true, but I am going to need to check when each is false and where one is true and the other is false.

Comment: @Beez Okay, figured as much. So either pass them to the function or have multiple computational functions that you call based off an if-else block in main.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I determine if their are True or False in main() I want to pass the values of them into my function computeDifference() I don't want to send them back like my other references(i.e. int& hours, int& minutes, etc...) I want to bring them in with the values they were assigned in main().

Comment: @Beez then what's wrong with just passing them to the function? `int computeDifference(int& hours, int& minutes, int& hourFut, int& minFut, bool isAm, bool isAMFut)`

Comment: [boolean arguments considered harmfull](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524)